# Dell Latitude D820 Max Screen Resolution

Tags: dell-latitude

I have a dell latitude d820 and the maximum resolution that I could see in the display properties windows under settings tab is 1280 x 800. Is there any where to increase the max resolution to 1400 x 1080?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those machines were built with a variety of screen resolutions, so it depends on how it was ordered. If your device drivers are current, then what you see in the settings is what you get.

Comment: Based on your response and the settings I see in my display properties, the max resolution I get is 1280 x 800. Is there any way to upgrade this by switching Video Card or some sort?

Comment: the only way to get a higher res. now is to either have the screen replaced or connect the laptop to an external display

Answer (score 2):

It depends of the type of the LCD screen (i.e. of what you ordered):

- 15.4” WXGA (1280 X 800 resolution)
- 15.4” WSXGA+ (1680 X 1050 resolution)
- 15.4” WUXGA (1920 X 1200 resolution)

Comment: How to find out if mine is WXGA or WSXGA+ or WUXGA?

Comment: Well, if you can't go beyond 1280 x 800, then you very likely have a WXGA. It should be possible to change the LCD. See for example http://www.lcds4less.com/DellLaptop__dell_latitude_d820__laptop-screens.html.

Comment: But is there any direct way to find out what kind of monitor I have, probably looking in hardware profiles (which I have already checked and there is no mention of screen type or something like that...?

Comment: Go to dell.com support and enter the machine's "service tag" number - it should tell you how the machine was equipped when it was built.